# How to get first top five objects with django.views.generic.date_based.archive_index?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-generic-views

I'm trying to display the latest 5 posts using a generic view like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^$', 'django.views.generic.date_based.archive_index', 
  {
      'queryset': Post.objects.all()[:5], 
      'date_field': 'created_on', 
      'template_name': 'index.html'}
  })
```

However I am getting

> AssertionError at /
>
> Cannot filter a query once a slice has
>   been taken.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num_latest: The number of latest objects to send to the template context. By default, it's 15.`